# managing C-strings from blocks, NSAlert, OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I’ve written a piece of test code "AlertTest" to make sure I’m implementing **NSAlert** object the proper way. It consists of a button which triggers **[doSomething: cstr]** printing a C-string, and a method posting an alert, which passes the same string to the same method, but from within the completion handler.
This is the debugger console printout:

-from **[buttonPressed]**

```
2015-01-09 18:28:09.832 AlertTest[1260:40881] Application must quit
Application must quit
```

-from **[mPostError:cstr]**

```
2015-01-09 18:28:12.276 AlertTest[1260:40881] @Èø_ˇ
@\351\277_\377
```

I’m a bit confused on what I have to do to properly pass a string from within the completion handler. No compiler errors reported. I must be missing something very obvious. Thanks in advance. Here’s the code:

```
//___________________________________________________________
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(NSButton *)sender {
char cstr[256];
strcpy(cstr, "Application must quit");
[self mDoSomething:cstr];
[self mPostError:cstr];
}
//___________________________________________________________
-(void)mDoSomething: (char*)cstr
{
NSLog(@"%s",cstr);
printf("%s\n", cstr);
}
//___________________________________________________________
-(void) mPostError: (char *)cstr
{
char cMessage[64] = "Critical Error";
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithCString:cMessage encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *infoText = [NSString stringWithCString:cstr encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSAlert* mAlert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
[mAlert setMessageText:message];
[mAlert setInformativeText:infoText];
[mAlert setAlertStyle: NSCriticalAlertStyle];
[mAlert beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {
 [self mDoSomething: cstr]; //this is the suspect line!
}];
}
```

Comment: Why are you using C strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is nothing to do with C-strings but with variable *lifetime*.

Your execution flow goes as follows:

1. `buttonPressed:` is called. This creates a local variable `cstr` and calls `mPostError:`
2. `mPostError:` is called. This calls `beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:` passing it a block. That block references `cstr` so a copy is made of the value in `cstr`, and that value is the address of `buttonPressed:`'s local variable of the same name.
3. `mPostError:` returns which gets us back to...
4. `buttonPressed:` which in turn returns *destroying* its local variable `cstr`. The block passed to `beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:` now has the address pointing into released memory.
5. The user dismisses the alert and the block is called. That block calls `mDoSomething:` passing it the, *now invalid*, address.
6. `mDoSomething:` calls `printf` which tries to interpret the memory at the passed address as a C-string, but by now that memory has been re-used for something else and it produces the nonsense you see.

Passing a C-string is not a problem, but whatever value (a `char *` value in this case) is passed to a block must be valid at the time the block is executed.

You can "fix" the issue in your example by making `cstr` a global variable:

```
char cstr[256]; // global

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(NSButton *)sender {
   strcpy(cstr, "Application must quit");
```

Now `cstr` *always* exists and the address the block copies is therefore always valid.

Of course you've now also permanently used up 256 bytes of memory and if this string is only required for a short period that is a (small) waste.

In your real code this may not be an issue - the C strings may be managed already so they live as long as required. If not and using C strings is a requirement then you may need to look at dynamically allocating them (see `malloc` and friends) and releasing them when no longer needed (see `free`).

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your comment on lifetime of the variable.

Comment: I try my best to stay away from, and discourage using global variables unless indispensable. In fact, declaring the string as **static char cstr[256];** fixes the problem. It's only for the test and demonstration purpose. In real app it's a bit more complex. Nevertheless, the 256 bytes are being used only once in app's lifetime, if ever at all.

Comment: Yes `static` on the in-function declaration will also work - that changes the lifetime to be whole program execution, just as for globals, but limits the visibility of the name to within the function.